# AWS realtime visualization

Tags: amazon-web-services, visualization

Are there any tools out there that would allow me to visualize my AWS instances in real-time ? For example, if I'm using auto-scaling I would be able to see the load on each instance and the scaling in real-time.

Comment: EC2 web console? CloudWatch dashboards? Third party monitoring services like NewRelic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon EC2 management console has a **Monitoring** tab that provides graphs for CPU, Network and Disk metrics.

You can **select multiple instances** to view them all on one chart. Click the chart to make it bigger.

Similar statistics are available in the Amazon CloudWatch management console.

See documentation: [Graph Metrics for Your Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/graphs-in-the-aws-management-console.html)